# Adding a closure as a struct method

Tags: rust

I'm trying to do this: where calling `modify()` will update the `r` with the environment variables.

I read about closures but don't  know how to add a closure to a struct.

```
fn main() {
    let r = Rect::new();
    let width:u32 = 10;
    let height:u32 = 10;

    r.modify();
}


struct Rect{
    width:u32,
    height:u32
}
impl Rect{
    fn new()->Self{
        Self{
            width:0,
            height:0,
        }
    }

    fn modify(&mut self){
        self.width = ...;
        self.height = ...;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok , I think what I want is impossible since closures capture environment variables at the time of defining for one.

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Environmental variables can be gotten via the items in `std::env`, but the wording of your question makes me think you're using the term "environmental variables" for something else. And what makes you think you need a closure? What exactly are you trying to solve?

Comment: yeah, environment variables being the scope the closure is being executed in. Well, my use case is that instead of passing a bunch of parameters into my function to create a struct, I could just reuse the variables from the outer scope to the closure scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want, try it!

```
fn main() {
    let mut r = Rect::new();
    let width: u32 = 10;
    let height: u32 = 11;
    let cls = || (width, height);

    r.modify(cls);
    dbg! {r};
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Rect {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
}

impl Rect {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self {
            width: 0,
            height: 0,
        }
    }

    fn modify<T>(&mut self, cls: T)
    where
        T: Fn() -> (u32, u32)
    {
        self.width = cls().0;
        self.height = cls().1;
    }
}
```